# Most significant Congressional Leaders in US History?

Tags: us-congress

In all of US history, which Congressional marjority/minority leaders and speakers are considered historically important?  For example, FDR and Lincoln are, for better or worse, considered historically important Presidents.

Comment: Ok, well it seems you know where I am going, but you don't like where I am going.  I'd just like to ask about Congressional leaders in a way that narrows them down to a few.  Back later.

Comment: @Mr.A I think if you restructured the question to be focused on the WHY leadership positions in the House or Senate are powerful that might help your question out. I like the spirit of the question, but it's wording is a little problematic.

Comment: Asking for the "why" were they powerful seems to invite a list which isn't really what we aim for in questions.

Comment: I'm sorry @SamuelRussell, I rolled back. I think I know what you are trying to do, but I could not understand your question or what was asked. Mr. A's question was understandable.

Comment: You should/could read [Robert Caro](http://www.robertcaro.com/)'s *Master Of The Senate*.

Comment: This is a [list question](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/667/1401)  and it strikes me as an opinion question.

Comment: Since the last try didn't take, I've taken a simpler crack at improving the question.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most famous and historically significant US Congressional leader was [Henry Clay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Clay), who was a dominant, if not *the* dominant leader of the early 19th Century Congress. He was the founder and leader of [the Whig party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whig_Party_%28United_States%29) (one of the two main parties of the era), and was the driving force behind [The Missouri Compromise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missouri_Compromise_of_1820) and (as a Senator) [The Compromise of 1850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compromise_of_1850), both of which for a time defused major pre-Civil war Slavery crises.

The role of Speaker regained a lot of power in the mid 20'th Century under [Sam Rayburn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Rayburn), but never really the same stature. During part of his tenure, his protege Lyndon Johnson asumed similar control of the Senate, producing a fairly imposing legislative partnership.